# updating python file that listens to postgres notify trigger without missing any triggers during update process

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, triggers

I have a python process that listens to some postgres notify calls from certain triggers

Occasionally I have the need to update this file, add some functionality / fix bugs whatever.

Currently am uploading the file and replacing existing
Kill the python process
Run tests
Restart processes

However, if a trigger is fired that causes a notify during the above, my process is not listening to it and it gets missed.

Are there any options here besides taking down the website, so no actions that would trigger a notify can occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to acquire a lock on something, a dedicated table for example.

The first thing the trigger would do is to try to acquire a lock on this table and release it at the end of the procedure.

When you want to start maintenance, manually acquire lock on this table (or script it) and your trigger will have to wait for the lock to be released to continue execution:

```
-- In the trigger code
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE maintenance IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
-- some code
COMMIT; -- lock on maintenance is released



-- Maintenance start
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE maintenance IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

-- Maintenance end
COMMIT; -- lock on maintenance is released
```

Here is the [postgresql lock documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-lock.html).

Comment: That works for me, nice and simple. Didn't even cross my mind to go down this avenue. Cheers